# Custom Rails Voting System Routes Not Working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

Hi I have a little app that has user, question, response and vote models:

```
class Vote < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :response

  enum vote_type: [ :upvote, :downvote]

  validates :response, uniqueness: { scope: :user }
  validates :user, uniqueness: { scope: :response }

end


class Response < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :question
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :votes
end


class Question < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user
    has_many :responses
end
```

I want to create a link to upvote and downvote the response

So in the app/controllers/questions/responses/votes_controller.rb

```
class Questions::Responses::VotesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :set_response


  def upvote
    @user = current_user
    vote = Vote.new
    vote.response = @response
    vote.user = @user
    if vote.save
      vote.upvote!
      redirect_to @response.question, notice: 'Response was successfully Upvoted.' 
    else
      redirect_to @response.question, notice: 'No Vote' 
    end
  end

  def downvote
    @user = current_user
    vote = Vote.new
    vote.response = @response
    vote.user = @user
    if vote.save
      vote.downvote!
      redirect_to @response.question, notice: 'Response was successfully DownVote.'
    else
      redirect_to @response.question, notice: 'No Vote' 
    end
  end

  private

  def set_response
    @response = Response.find(params[:response_id])
  end

end
```

I created the routes

```
resources :questions do
    resources :responses, module: :questions do
      resources :votes, module: :responses, only: [:upvote, :downvote]
    end
  end
```

but this doesn't work

when i remove the ", only: [:upvote, :downvote]"

it creates routes

```
question_response_votes GET    /questions/:question_id/responses/:response_id/votes(.:format)                           questions/responses/votes#index
                                      POST   /questions/:question_id/responses/:response_id/votes(.:format)                           questions/responses/votes#create
           new_question_response_vote GET    /questions/:question_id/responses/:response_id/votes/new(.:format)                       questions/responses/votes#new
          edit_question_response_vote GET    /questions/:question_id/responses/:response_id/votes/:id/edit(.:format)                  questions/responses/votes#edit
               question_response_vote GET    /questions/:question_id/responses/:response_id/votes/:id(.:format)                       questions/responses/votes#show
                                      PATCH  /questions/:question_id/responses/:response_id/votes/:id(.:format)                       questions/responses/votes#update
                                      PUT    /questions/:question_id/responses/:response_id/votes/:id(.:format)                       questions/responses/votes#update
                                      DELETE /questions/:question_id/responses/:response_id/votes/:id(.:format)                       questions/responses/votes#destroy
```

I only want to upvote or downvote... can someone tell me how? or what I am doing wrong?

**Update**

With help from the response below I found the correct routes to be

```
resources :questions do
    resources :responses, module: :questions do
      get 'upvote', controller: 'responses/votes', as: :upvote
      get 'downvote', controller: 'responses/votes', as: :downvote
      resource :favourite, module: :responses, only: [:create, :destroy]
    end
  end
```

with the links

```
<%= link_to question_response_upvote_path(response.question.id ,response) %>

<%= link_to question_response_downvote_path(response.question.id ,response) %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With help from the @crachtors response I found the correct routes to be

```
resources :questions do
    resources :responses, module: :questions do
      get 'upvote', controller: 'responses/votes', as: :upvote
      get 'downvote', controller: 'responses/votes', as: :downvote
      resource :favourite, module: :responses, only: [:create, :destroy]
    end
  end
```

with the links

```
<%= link_to question_response_upvote_path(response.question.id ,response) %>

<%= link_to question_response_downvote_path(response.question.id ,response) %>
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you haven't actually created the custom routes for upvote or downvote, you have only specified which actions in the controller should be resourced.

So you need to create a POST route in your `routes.rb` in the same format specified under POST when you run the command `rake routes`.

Like this:

```
post '/questions/:question_id/responses/:response_id/upvote' => 'votes_controller#upvote', :as => :upvote
```

`:as => :upvote` creates the `upvote_path` which you then can `<%= link_to %>` or add in the form_for however you choose to reference upvotes in your views.

Comment: your answer results in the No route matches [GET] "/questions/1/responses/1/upvote"

Comment: What does your form_for look like?

Comment: there is no form for.... its a link.... I simply need to hit the correct upvote or downvote path with a post. so i could add the method to the link

Comment: You could just change the post to get in the routes. or add :method => "post" to the link_to

Comment: could i type as: :upvote? I am just not used to the arrows and notice its used alot with earlier versions of rails

Comment: You need to type it as  `<%= link_to upvote_path ....... %>` or you could do; (although this is not the rails way) `<%= link_to :url => "/questions/#{@question.id}/responses/#{@response.id}/upvote"... %>` Tons of ways to link in rails.